# Not-quite gradient of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of ints:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0,1,0,2,2,5,2,4], 
                    [0,1,0,0,2,2,4,5,3,3], 
                    [1,1,1,1,2,2,0,4,4,4]])
```

I'd like to calculate something that resembles the gradient given by `pd.Series.dff()` for each row, but with one big change: my ints represent categorical data, so I'm only interested in detecting a change, not the magnitude of it. So the step from 0 to 1 should be the same as the step from 0 to 4.

Is there a way for pandas to interpret my data as categorical in the data frame, and then calculate a `Series.diff()` on that? Or could you "flatten" the output of `Series.diff()` to be only 0s and 1s?

Comment: `.diff()` is not performed on 'Categorical' type. What is the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this is what you are trying to achieve:

```
import pandas as pd
mydf = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0,1,0,2,2,5,2,4], 
                    [0,1,0,0,2,2,4,5,3,3], 
                    [1,1,1,1,2,2,0,4,4,4]])

mydf = mydf.astype("category")

diff_df = mydf.apply(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0), axis=1).astype(int)
```

The `ne` returns a boolean array which indicates if the difference between consecutive values is different from zero. Then you use the `astype`  to convert the boolean values to integers (0s and 1s). The result is a dataframe with the same number of rows as the original dataframe, and the same number of columns, but with binary values indicating a change in the categorical value from one step to the next.

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0
2  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0
```

Comment: Yep this is basically what I wanted to see! Thank you for your answer. One small issue: the first ``period` values of the output of `pd.Series.dff()` are all `NaN`s, due to the edge of the df. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Or would it just be best to force the first column of the output df to 0?

Comment: You will need to ```fillna(0)```